# XMLHttpRequest returning PHP code, not PHP output

Tags: java, php, json, xmlhttprequest

This is my first time using PHP and XMLHttpRequest, and I'm not sure where I messed up.

Here's my javascript code: (newsmanager.js)

```
function getNews(){

  var httpReq;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    httpReq=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    httpReq=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  try {
    httpReq.open("GET", "../news/newsgetter.php", false);
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
    httpReq.send(null);
  } catch(e) {
    alert("ERROR: " + e);
  }

  function stateChange() {
    //convert result to JSON
    alert(httpReq.readyState);
    alert(httpReq.responseText);
    var result = JSON.parse(httpReq.responseText);
    loadNews(result);
  }

}

function loadNews(result){ //its an ARRAY
  alert("test 2");
  var newsContainer = document.getElementById("news-holder");
  var html = '<hr>';

  for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

    html += result[i];
    html += '<hr>';

  }

  newsContainer.innerHTML=html;

}
```

and here's my PHP code:

```
<?php

  //folder relative to this file
  $dir = "messages";
  //array holding all addresses
  $result = array();

  //get files in directory
  $files = scandir($dir);

  while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false){
    //find MD files
    if(strlen($file) < 3 || substr($file, -4) != '.md')
        continue;

    $result[] = $dir . "/" . $file; 
  }

  //convert array to JSON
  echo(json_encode($result));

?>
```

The problem is that the httpReq.responseText returns the PHP code itself, not the array from the echo. I've been reading over this several times and I don't see why this problem is being caused. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is your web server running?

Comment: Yes. The host is Github Pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable/configure php to work with your webserver.
Your webserver returns your php code because it does not know that is should execute it.
Look on the web for a tutorial on how to install php on your OS/Webserver.